# VBA Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ado

I'm trying to insert some data into SQL from Excel VBA. The SQL commands are built up over the course of the VBA script, and include the use of some SQL variables.

I'm trying to understand how transactions work in VBA, and whether they will work with what I need to do, I have the code below that will test this, but it does not work. It always gives me an error about "Must define scalar variable @name" so I assume there is an issue here with the scope of the data/transaction. How can I get this simple code to work?

```
Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;" & _
"Initial Catalog=ImportTest;" & _
"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress"  

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
   .CursorLocation = adUseClient
   .Open stADO
   .CommandTimeout = 0     
End With

cn.BeginTrans
cn.Execute "set implicit_transactions off"
cn.Execute ("declare @name varchar(100)")    
cn.Execute ("set @name='name'")    
cn.Execute ("Insert into test (id,name) values (55,@name)")
cn.CommitTrans    

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Donning my Captain Obvious suit here. Have you considered using stored proc?

Comment: @conrad Yeah, unfortunately the SQL code is generated dynamically and will vary wildly with each use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to execute all these in 1 batch

```
cn.Execute "set implicit_transactions off"
cn.Execute ("declare @name varchar(100)")
cn.Execute ("set @name='name'")
cn.Execute ("Insert into test (id,name) values (55,@name)")
```

built a string and then use 1 cn.Execute

Better yet, use parameterized queries to guard against `SQL injection`

Comment: That's what I thought I might need to do, I was trying to avoid building a giant string if I could (the actual SQL script will be a lot larger than this) but if it's not possible then I will have to do that.