# Excel VBA - mySQL Update command fails multiple lines

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am trying to switch some of my excel vba code to connection/command strings.  I have the code that works using connections / recordsets / etc.

I have an odbc driver connection set up correctly.  I am creating the sql statement from code.  If I only have 1 line, it works.  If I try 2 or more, I get a vba automation runtime error '-2147217900 (80040e14).

Here is the sql statements
This one works

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblMat_Prices SET Price = '50' WHERE ID = '4';"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute
```

But if strSql is more than 1 line, then it doesn't work

```
srtSQL= "UPDATE tblMat_Prices SET Price = '50' WHERE ID = '4';
UPDATE tblMat_Prices SET Price = '50' WHERE ID = '5';"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute
```

Anyone have any pointers for me?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Correct, you can only have one SQL command for each execute.

Comment: So rather than building a multiple line strSQL command (multiple updates), I have to run a cmd.execute against each update line?

I thought from reading (google-ing) that the execute would process all the lines one by one.

Comment: Correct. So you have better look up how to make this into a Transaction so you can maintain database intergity when doing multiple related updates

Comment: I used the sql statement from MySQL Workbench as my "example".  When I change fields in the table thru it and it apply, it gives me an sql statement to review.  I then hit apply and it processes.  Is it actually running an execute statement against each line that I'm not seeing?  I assumed it was running just 1 execute against the entire thing.

Thank you for the help.  This has had me stumped for a day and a half. :(

Comment: transaction....this is a new one to me.  I'll start a new google search crusade.

Thank you.

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451026/vba-transactions

Comment: Off topic question....how do I mark this as answered and how to I add a "thanks" to your profile (if that is possible)

(I'm pretty new to stackoverflow)

Comment: Best to just delete the question.